# De-select when user double-click on anywhere using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

As you know, when a user **double-click** somewhere, Explorer tries to select the nearest objects (such as text, table-row etc.) like the picture below:
[image]

### User can:

- select any text with one-click

### User can't

- select any object with double-click (in other words, when the user double-clicks on the list, jquery should deselect *selected area*)

So how can I do this? Hope it's clear.

**Note:** I use double-click operation to enter the item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot, this is one of those edge cases where the default action can't be cancelled in the event.  In that case, you might want to use the CSS approach for Firefox and Chrome:

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

And for Opera/IE:

```
$("#mytable td").prop("unselectable", "on");  // jQuery 1.6+
$("#mytable td").attr("unselectable", "on");  // jQuery 1.5-
```

---

If you want the user to still be able to drag-select, you might want to work in a solution like this:

```
$("#mytable td").bind("dblclick", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prop("unselectable", "on").css({ 
        "moz-user-select" : "none", 
        "-webkit-user-select" : "none"
    });

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop("unselectable", "").css({ 
            "moz-user-select" : "", 
            "-webkit-user-select" : ""
        });
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: @andy: thanks your answer, but I use double-click operation. I just need to cancel selection.

Comment: @dino: then you just need to incorporate my answer into your current solution - the easiest way is adding `return false;` to the end of your handler.

Comment: @andy: too strange, i still select any object in my table even tough i used your code. it should work, isn't it?

Comment: @andy: thank you Andy. Almost finished. If I use your CSS code, user can't select anything. That's not good. But your script works well for IE as you mentioned (we need Chrome/Firefox). Maybe you want to change CSS code with this jquery: `$('#mytable td').dblclick(function(){   
   $(this).css('user-select', 'none'); $(this).css('-webkit-user-select', 'none');
    });`

Comment: @dino: yeah, you might want to reset afterwards using a timer.  I've updated again.

Answer (score 0):

pick some random element and

```
$("#randsmallelement").focus();
```

if that doesn't work try adding

```
$("#randsmallelement).select();
```

Comment: thanks thought. but your answer is not about question, i think.